# How to know if a linear map matrix is diagonalizable knowing about the kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $T: \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ be a linear map with characteristic polynomial $pt(x)$.

Is $T$ diagonalizable in the following cases?

1. $pt(x) = x^4-1$
2. $pt(x) = x^3(x+1)$ and $\dim \ker(T) = 2$
3. $pt(x) = x^2(x^2- 4)$ and $\dim \ker(T) = 2$

For the first case, I concluded that $T$ is not diagonalizable because the roots of the characteristic polynomial are $x1 = 1$, $x2 = -1$, $x3 = i$, $ x4 = -i$. Is this correct?

What do I do on the other cases?

Thanks and sorry for anything not well explained, this is my first question here.

Comment: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: You repeated two roots of $\;x^4-1\;$ . These should be $\;\pm 1\;,\;\;\pm i\;$ over the complex.

Comment: Thanks Timbuc, going to learn about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case you get 4 distinct eigenvalues: $\pm 1, \pm i$. So $T$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$: there are four eigenspaces in $\mathbb{C}^4$, each of (complex) dimension 1. Hence the eigenvectors span $\mathbb{C}^4$. Hence $T$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$. (It is not diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$, because it has non-real eigenvalues.)

In the second case you have 2 eigenvalues: $0$ and $-1$. The latter has multiplicity 1. The former has geometric multiplicity 2, and the space has dimension 4. So the eigenvectors do not span $\mathbb{R}^4$. So $T$ is not diagonalizable even over $\mathbb{C}$.

Now try the same idea on the third case.

Comment: I'd like to point out that $i \not\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I was slightly vague with "they" when I meant the eigenvectors, not the eigenvalues. I think this was probably clear in context.

Comment: You wrote "the eigenvectors span $\mathbb{R}^4$", that's simply false...

Comment: Like Najib said, the fact that i ∉ ℝ takes me to a domain that my linear map does is not defined. Isn't that right?

Comment: Sorry, forgot about the parenthesis. Thanks Ian.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi This depends on the base field. In my experience, when talking about diagonalizability we are really talking about diagonalizability over $\mathbb{C}$, not over $\mathbb{R}$. You're right, the eigenvectors do not span $\mathbb{R}^4$ when the field of scalars is $\mathbb{R}$. They do span $\mathbb{R}^4$ (in fact $\mathbb{C}^4$) when the field of scalars is $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: The information about the Kernel is useless in this case?

Comment: @LucasHelfstein The dimension of the kernel is the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue $0$. In the second case the algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalue $0$ is $3$ while the geometric multiplicity is $2$. The fact that $2<3$ is why $T$ is not diagonalizable.

Comment: Hmmm, I didn't know that. Thanks one more time.